# Foreach command not found

Tags: command-line

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.4. I'd previously used the foreach command on older Ubuntu versions without a problem, but now I'm getting "command not found". Not sure if this is due to a newer version of ubuntu, or if something went wrong during installation. 
Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Ben

Comment: `foreach` is not a shell command and has never been. Maybe you remember programming in `php`

Comment: Welcome! What is the context in which you want to use it? And where did you use it before?

Answer (score 4):

`foreach` is a construct in the C shell and its variants (`csh` or Tenex `tcsh` for example).

Ex.

```
#!/bin/csh

foreach i (`seq 1 3`)
  echo "$i"
end
```

The default interactive shell used in Ubuntu is `bash`, where the equivalent syntax would be

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(seq 1 3); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

If you have older scripts that rely on `csh`, you can install the BSD `csh` package and/or Tenex `tcsh` package from the Ubuntu repository. However please see [Top Ten Reasons not to use the C shell](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/CshTop10.txt).